# How does a resistor work?

Tags: electrical-resistance

How is it, that a resistor can physically resist current? Do electrons collide with the materials lattice which is what causes resistance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electrical Resistance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406451/)